# Full Screen Activity - System UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fullscreen

I have a full screen activity with a Text View in it, the text view activity is created programmatically. When the System UI is shown this text view doesn't remain at the same place but it descends to where the upper part of the System UI ends. I tried different layout parameters but none of them worked so far.

Comment: What is "the System UI"?

Comment: Status Bar and Navigation Bar

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html see system bars and how they work with full screen.